# concatenating strings to use on the command line

Tags: c

My assignment wants me to gather all the processes being run by using a ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep <PID#> I need to use, but I am receiving an illegal hardware instruction. here is the code:

```
//some code^

int PID = getpid();
char command[] = "ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep ";
char PIDString[12];

sprintf(PIDString, "%i", PID);
system("clear");

//These print just fine
//printf("%s\n",command);
//printf("ID %s",PIDString);

strcat(command, PIDString);

system(command);
```

When I tried to insert a %i. into the string "grep ...%.." it wouldn't work. Is there a way to do this instead of changing the int to a string and concatenating them. Please let me know what I'm missing to grasp.

Comment: The `grep -v grep` is unnecessary when you are grepping for a PID, and if you're on anything remotely modern the entire mess can be replaced with `ps -p %i -f`.

Comment: I may have understated what I needed exactly, he wants to see the current processes and the parent processes as well to make sure all my forks start and end.

Comment: ... are you supposed to be implementing pipelines yourself then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char command[] = "ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep ";
```

Your compiler will allocate just enough memory to hold this string.

If you want to have additional space available, you could make sure by specifying the size of the array.

```
char command[100] = "ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep ";
```

You may wish to define a constant to hold that value, rather than just a magic number.

Comment: I had a feeling it had to do with space allocation. Thank you